# Spring Data JPA Map Query Params with JPA Query to retrieve records from Postgresql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, query-string

I have a `@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams`. The controller takes queryParams from UI end to request JPA Repository and return records from the database.

Is there a way to directly send this `MultiValueMap` to the repository interface and fetch records based on `queryParams`?

I have a `UserRepository` which *extends* `JPARepository<User, Long>`.
The controller has a method which takes `@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams` as an input and needs to appropriately fetch records from the database and store it in a `List<User>`.

Ex: if `url = /api/users?name=USER123&salary=10000&department=science`

I can neither use `@PathVariable` because there are many such attributes in User which can be used for querying, nor have 1 method for each combination of `queryParams`.

I need to send the `queryParams` to fetch exact records matching the query parameters.

```
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getSpecificUsers(
    Pageable pageable,
    @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams
) {}
```

If there is a way to generate `@Query` based on the `RequestParam` query params I am open to use that as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The JPA criteria API, or QueryDSL, are both designed to do that: generate a query dynamically based on criteria. Note that you could use a Command class, with named and typed properties, instead of a MultiValueMap.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.I shall take care of the formatting next time. @JBNizet I wanted to know if we could use a `MultiValueMap` instead of String params. And could you please elaborate what is the `Command class` and what you mean by `named` and `typed` properties?

Comment: I cannot have each method for a set of params. 
i.e., if I have a query like /api/users?name=USER123&salary=10000&department=science
I cannot go on writing methods for each of this parameter. 

I need something which does not make me have to write all the possible query criteria in a class.

Comment: That's why you would dynamically create the query, in a single method, thanks to the criteria API. A command class with named and types properies wouldbe, in the above example, a class with a property "name" of type String, a property salary of type Integer, and a department of type DepartmentEnum, for example. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args

Comment: I tried using `SpecificationBuilder` and used `findAll(specification)` method and it worked. I have also added a toPredicate method. I followed [REST Query Language.](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-query-search-language-more-operations) tutorial to achieve this.
Thanks for your timely help.